# Flake8-linter Atom include excluded files

Tags: atom-editor, flake8, linter

I somehow excluded all my "admin.py" files from linter-flake8 2.0.2 for atom.
So every file is perfectly monitored by the linter-flake8 except my admin.py files in different folders.
I don't know how that happened. It's not in the .flake8 - configuration excludes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it works again...
reinstall linter or atom-linter plugin won't work. But reopen the project folder does fix the bug...